# initialize tabPanel input values Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app where there are two tabPanels in a tabsetPanel.  The widgets in the tabPanels are dynamically created based on values in a data frame (called stager) that is loaded from mySQL.  The input values (selected) for the second tabPanel checkbox are only initialized when the the tab is clicked on but I want them initialized when the Shiny app is run.  The server and UI code is below:

Server code (2nd tabPanel):

```
  output$Box4 = renderUI(checkboxGroupInput('showcols',
                                            'Columns to show:',
                                            names(stager2()),
                                            selected = names(stager2()[c(1,6,10,11,14,15,18,19,20)])))
```

UI code (2nd tabPanel):

```
  tabPanel("Select Columns", 
           hr(),
           uiOutput("Box4")
  )
```

Any ideas on how to get the input values to initialize when the app is run are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you played around with the `observe` function at all?

http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observe.html

I haven't personally used it for that sort of thing, but it may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks.  I will research the observe function.  In the interim I was able to initialize the input values by making them reactive and using an if else to set them based on if they existed.  To see if they existed I had to use:  if (is.character(input$showcols).

Comment: Could you please Answer with your own solution @RAC and accept the Answer. It may complete this chain and if it works for me I will upvote the question and the answer. Thanks